# Undeclared identifier

Tags: solidity, identity

```
pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

contract Origin {

struct OriginInfo
{
    string airportName;
    uint32 checkInTime; //In timestamp
    uint8 bagWeight;
    address clientAddress;
    bool itsHere;
}
mapping (uint256 => OriginInfo) origins;
uint256 public originNonce;

constructor() public
{
    originNonce = 1;
}

function insertOrigin(string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight) 
    external 
{
    origins[originNonce] = OriginInfo(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight, msg.sender, true);
    originNonce += 1;

    recoverOrigin(originNonce);
}

function recoverOrigin(uint256 _originId) 
    private view //cambiar a private 
    returns (string, uint32, uint8, address, bool) 
{
    OriginInfo memory origin = origins[_originId];
    return (
        origin.airportName,
        origin.checkInTime, 
        origin.bagWeight, 
        origin.clientAddress, 
        origin.itsHere
    );
}
}



pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

import "./TraceabilityProcedures/Origin.sol";

contract Travel is Origin{


struct TravelInfo {

    Origin origin;
}

mapping(uint => Travel) travels;
uint public travelsRegistryCount;

function addOrigin (string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight){
    insertOrigin(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight);

}

}
```

I have this files and I not able to declare de identifier because I dont now what is the problem. The problema appear here:

> insertOrigin(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight);

Any help??

**EDIT:**

```
pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

contract Origin {

struct OriginInfo
{
    string airportName;
    uint32 checkInTime; //In timestamp
    uint8 bagWeight;
    address clientAddress;
    bool itsHere;
}
mapping (uint256 => OriginInfo) origins;
uint256 public originNonce;

constructor() public
{
    originNonce = 1;
}

function insertOrigin(string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight) 
    public 
{
    origins[originNonce] = OriginInfo(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight, msg.sender, true);
    originNonce += 1;

    recoverOrigin(originNonce);
}

function recoverOrigin(uint256 _originId) 
    private view //cambiar a private 
    returns (string, uint32, uint8, address, bool) 
{
    OriginInfo memory origin = origins[_originId];
    return (
        origin.airportName,
        origin.checkInTime, 
        origin.bagWeight, 
        origin.clientAddress, 
        origin.itsHere
    );
}
}

pragma solidity ^ "0.4.24";

import "./TraceabilityProcedures/Origin.sol";
import "./TraceabilityProcedures/Tape.sol";
import "./TraceabilityProcedures/Plane.sol";
import "./TraceabilityProcedures/Destiny.sol";

contract Travel{


struct TravelInfo {
    uint test;
    //Origin origin;
}

mapping(uint => Travel) travels;
uint public travelsRegistryCount;

function addOrigin (string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight) public {
    insertOrigin(_airportName, _checkInTime, _bagWeight);

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have marked the `insertOrigin()` function as `external`, but it needs to be marked `public` since you are making an internal call the way you have written your code.

```
function insertOrigin(string _airportName, uint32 _checkInTime, uint8 _bagWeight) 
    public 
{
    ...
}
```

Take a look at the [visibility documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters).

> External functions are part of the contract interface, which means
>   they can be called from other contracts and via transactions. An
>   external function f **cannot be called internally** (i.e. f() does not
>   work, but this.f() works).

To be more clear here, since you wrote `contract Travel is Origin`, you have then absorbed all the functions from `Origin` into your `Travel` contract, thus these are all internal function. If instead, `Origin` was deployed on its own to a specific address, and then you made your new Travel contract call those functions as transactions between the two contracts, then `external` would be the right thing to do.

Comment: I change the is attribute but the problem persist. I update the question

Comment: I undestand. The idea was to import the file but no inherit. Just import to call the function and get some parameters.